# How to enable write ahead logging in FMDB iOS?

Tags: ios, database, fmdb, wal

I wanna enable **write ahead logging** in FMDB.
I am using objective c and iOS 8.
Please help me.

Comment: Hi! Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

`[fmdatabase executeUpdate:@"PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;"];`

Comment: ```[dbQueue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase * _Nonnull db) { [db executeUpdate:@"PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;"]; }];```
this worked very well.